# Google Cloud Storage Client - Set Object ACL so project A can access storage in project B

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have project B that has storage enabled, and I need project A to access this storage in project B.
Using Google Cloud Storage, I need to set the **ACL** when creating or replacing the object, how to do that ?

This is possible using developer console.

Comment: You can use the cloudstorage json API or API client to set the ACL

Comment: The problem with this API that's not robust, for example you need to implement your own retry handler on transient errors, and this is not straight forward with Google, as there is no documentation for transient errors/exceptions.

Comment: Problem? Here is my code for both options using Python: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-acl-insert-delete

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't use it and implement my own retry for example.